# Dojo lightbox problem

Tags: dojo, lightbox, modular

I made a custom basic lightbox with Dojo to be used with forms and data. Not really dealing with images or such.

The problem that I seem to be facing is this. When Dojo makes a call via AJAX to ajaxtb.php with specific code for example; ?f=login or ?f=register the page is loaded. When you I close the lightbox and try to view something different say ?f=stuff the lightbox will show what ever was before it be it ?f=login or what ever, it will show it until ?f=stuff is fully loaded.

Here is the code for the lightbox, also can some one tell me how to optimize it since its pretty redundant at the moment and very basic.

```
dojo.ready(function(){ 

    #loads logout confirmation      
    dojo.query("#jsLogoutPromp").connect("onclick", function(){

                                 dojo.byId("qpbox-title-text").innerHTML = "Logout Confirmation";

                                 dojo.query("#qpbox-content").style("display", "block");
                                 dojo.query("#qpbox-overlay").style("display", "block");

                                 dojo.xhrGet({
                                 url: "ajaxtb.php?f=logout",

                                 load: function(newContent) {
                                 dojo.byId("utm").innerHTML = newContent;
                                 },
                                 // The error handler
                                 error: function() {
                                 // Do nothing -- keep old content there
                                 }
                                 });

    }); 

    #loads options to upload profile photo
    dojo.query("#jsUserPhotoPromp").connect("onclick", function(){

                                 dojo.byId("qpbox-title-text").innerHTML = "Upload Photo";

                                 dojo.query("#qpbox-content").style("display", "block");
                                 dojo.query("#qpbox-overlay").style("display", "block");

                                 dojo.xhrGet({
                                 url: "ajaxtb.php?f=display_pic",

                                 load: function(newContent) {
                                 dojo.byId("utm").innerHTML = newContent;
                                 },
                                 // The error handler
                                 error: function() {
                                 // Do nothing -- keep old content there
                                 }
                                 });

    });     

    #closes everything when clicked well technically hides everything           
    dojo.query("#qpbox-close").connect("onclick", function(){


                                 dojo.query("#qpbox-content").style("display", "none");
                                 dojo.query("#qpbox-overlay").style("display", "none"); 


   });  

   #shows up for logout only, same as above code, but does not work since the original id is included in ajax.php?f=logout 
   dojo.query("#qpbox-stay").connect("onclick", function(){


                                 dojo.query("#qpbox-content").style("display", "none");
                                 dojo.query("#qpbox-overlay").style("display", "none"); 


   });  

});
```

The functions responsible for closing everything is qpbox-close and qpbox-stay. Technically both only hide the lightbox not close. The other problem is with qpbox-stay. qpbox-stay id is located in ajax.php?f=logout and when clicked it does not close the lightbox so not sure whats the problem with it.

here is the code for ajax.php

```
if($_GET['f'] == 'logout') {

echo '
<p>Are you sure you want to exit right now?</p>
<br>
<button type="submit">Logout</button>  <a href="#meminipost" id="qpbox-stay" onClick="return false;" style="float: right;">No, I wana Stay</a>
';

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dojo.empty(dojo.byId('utm'))` before showing the lightbox to delete all the contents.

Also, you can refactor your code quite a bit. Both click handlers do basically the same thing. So why not refactor them in a function?

```
dojo.ready(function() {
  function showLightBox(title, url) {
    var utm = dojo.byId('utm');

    dojo.empty(utm);

    dojo.byId("qpbox-title-text").innerHTML = title;
    dojo.style(dojo.byId("qpbox-content"), "display", "block");
    dojo.style(dojo.byId("qpbox-overlay"), "display", "block");

    dojo.xhrGet({
      url: url,
      load: function(newContent) {
        utm.innerHTML = newContent;
      },
      // The error handler
      error: function() {
        // Do nothing -- keep old content there
      }
    });
  }

  function hideLightBox() {
    dojo.style(dojo.byId("qpbox-content"), "display", "none");
    dojo.style(dojo.byId("qpbox-overlay"), "display", "none");
  }

  dojo.connect(dojo.byId('jsLogoutPromp'), 'onclick', function() {
    showLightBox("Logout Confirmation", "ajaxtb.php?f=logout");
  });

  // ...

  dojo.connect(dojo.byId('qpbox-close'), 'onclick', hideLightBox);

});
```

You can try and connect to `#qpbox-stay` *after* you've loaded the content, or if using Dojo 1.6, you can use `NodeList.delegate` like:

```
dojo.require('dojox.NodeList.delegate');
dojo.query('#utm').delegate('#qpbox-stay', 'onclick', hideLightBox);
```

That will connect to `#utm` which is already loaded, but work for `#qpbox-stay` only. It works with event bubbling, similar to `jquery.live()`. See http://davidwalsh.name/delegate-event